# What are the differences between these three concepts, Animation, Transition and Transaction in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

These three concepts are all from Core Animation, but i don't really understand the difference  between them. Because animation and transition seems quite similar to me, and transaction as well.

Comment: What do you think currently?

Comment: @Wain maybe i am wrong, but i think transitions and animations are same, we can use animations to do the same effect that transitions did.

Answer (score 21):

Animation is a general term for making a view object change it's appearance smoothly from one state to another state over time.

A transition is a specific type of animation for switching between views, view controllers, or layers. The Core Animation framework includes specific calls to support transitions, as well as more general-purpose animations. There are also UIKit calls that handle view and view controller transitions. (See, for example, `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:`, `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:`, and `transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` )

A "transaction" is a Core Animation term that refers to a discrete set of UI changes that are grouped together and submitted to the Core Animation engine for rendering together as a group. Most of the time the system creates animation transactions for you behind the scenes as a result of your animation code (known as "implicit transactions".) Take a look at the Xcode docs for CATransaction for more information.